# The given contract doesn't exist in the blockchain

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, nodeos, transactions

I have got contract code below:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;

class deneme: contract {
   // @abi table  
   struct countries {
      name sender;
      string country;

      name primary_key() const { return sender; }
      EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( countries, (sender)(country) )
   };
public:
   deneme(account_name self):
    contract(self),
    _countries(_self, _self) {}

   multi_index< N(countries), countries > _countries;

  // @abi action
  void myaction(name sender,string country) {
    // add to table, first argument is account to bill for storage
     _countries.emplace(sender, [&](auto& row) {
        row.sender = sender;
        row.country = country;
     });
  }
};
EOSIO_ABI( deneme, (myaction) )
```

And generate wast and abi file with:

```
eosiocpp -o deneme.wast deneme.cpp
eosiocpp -g deneme.abi deneme.cpp
```

Deploy contract with (there was no change on nodeos terminal when setting contract):

```
cleos set contract eosio ../deneme -p eosio
```

Finally I try to push action like :

```
cleos push action deneme myaction '{"sender":"eosio","country":"anywhere"}' -p eosio
```

I've got an error below :

```
Error 3060004: Contract Query Exception
Most likely, the given contract doesnt' exist in the blockchain.
```

nodeos says:

```
162072ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception]
FC   Exception encountered while processing chain.abi_json_to_bin
162072ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception]
Exception Details: 3060004 contract_query_exception: Contract Query  
Exception
Contract can't be found deneme
{"contract":"deneme"}threadchain_plugin.cpp:1103   abi_json_to_bin{"params.code":"deneme","params.action":"myaction","params.args
{"sender":"eosio","country":"istanbul"}}thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:1119 abi_json_to_bin
```

Also when I set contract nodeos says nothing (no changes on nodeos terminal). Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you do want set the contract on eosio, you need push action to that account " cleos push action eosio myaction '{"sender":"eosio","country":"anywhere"}' -p eosio "

Answer (score 2):

You need to **set the contract to your deneme account** not to eosio.

For local development you have to do the following (considering you already have a wallet and unlocked it).

**Create two key pairs for active and owner**

```
cleos create key
```

Output:

```
Private key: <private_key_1>

Public key: EOS....xyz
```

run it **twice** and write down the key pairs

**Now import them to your wallet**

```
cleos wallet import <private_key_1> -n <wallet_name>
```

**Import the eosio private key for account creation:**

```
cleos wallet import 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3 -n <wallet_name>
```

**Then you need to create your account deneme**

```
cleos create account eosio deneme <owner_public_key> <active_public_key>
```

**Deploy to deneme account**

```
cleos set contract deneme <path_to_contract> <path_to_contract>/deneme.wast <path_to_contract>/deneme.abi -p deneme
```

**Test an action**

```
cleos push action deneme myaction '{"sender":"eosio","country":"anywhere"}' -p denem@active
```

Comment: you can also use "cleos wallet create_key", so there is no need to import the key

Answer (score 0):

cleos set contract `eosio`, should not be eosio, but `deneme`, and you must create an account for `deneme`